# Error Array to string conversion in this PDO PHP while inserting multiple data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to insert this array facing

> Array to string conversion error

**but data is inserting in DB**

```
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dentist", "root", "");
if (isset($_POST['problem'])) { 
$problem = $_POST['problem'];
$tooth = $_POST['tooth'];
$intervention = $_POST['intervention'];
```

For loop using to insert array

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($problem); $i++) {
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_finds (problem, tooth, intervention) 
VALUES ($problem[$i], $tooth[$i], $intervention[$i])";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['problem'], $_POST["tooth"], $_POST["intervention"]));}}
```

Comment: What are you asking for?

Comment: Facing "Array to string conversion Error" while run this code.

Comment: Have a read through https://stackoverflow.com/tour and post a question. The code you posted is also very likely to be exploitable by SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning values directly to the query as well as trying to bind them in next line using `execute()`.Don't do that.

Do like below:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_finds (problem, tooth, intervention) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
foreach($_POST['problem'] as $key=>$value){
    $stmt->execute(array($value, $_POST["tooth"][$key], $_POST["intervention"][$key]));
}
```

Complete code will be:

```
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dentist", "root", "");
if (isset($_POST['problem'])) { 
    $problem = $_POST['problem'];
    $tooth = $_POST['tooth'];
    $intervention = $_POST['intervention'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_finds (problem, tooth, intervention) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
    foreach($_POST['problem'] as $key=>$value){
        $stmt->execute(array($value, $_POST["tooth"][$key], $_POST["intervention"][$key]));
    }
}
```

***Note:-*** `$_POST['problem'], $_POST["tooth"], $_POST["intervention"]` all three are array so when you directly use them to bind as values to the query, you got that error.

Comment: @SomasundaramM  glad to help you :). Happy coding